# Finding new props that will fit

Tags: propellers

I have an old wifi drone with 2-blade props that I would like to upgrade to 3-blade props, but I'm having a hard time finding any that will fit my drone and I'm not familiar with the different methods that props are attached. Are there some attachments that are more common/standardized or do they basically just vary by manufacturer?

When I search around, most props seem to be made to screw down directly onto a rotor, but my drone has a configuration where each motor turns a gear that turns an axle and the props are fitted over this axle and then secured with a tiny screw from the side. Is there a name for that kind of attachment?

Here's a picture of the propeller, this might give a better idea of how it attaches:
[image: propeller]

Comment: Could you post a photo of your set up? it sounds quite unusual.

Comment: Yeah, it's an older drone and a toy so I guess all bets are off.

Comment: I would guess the motors are loaded pretty much to the limit with the existing props. You'd likely not find much improvement with 3 bladed props, as the motors would probably not be able to spin them effectively. These toy class drones aren't really designed with any overhead electromechanically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've never seen a prop attached like that, so I don't think you'll be able to find replacements.

However, as you have a shaft, you can get a collet prop adapter and then use props that are designed to bolt on.

[image: collet prop adapter]

These clamp onto a smooth shaft as you tighten the bolt. You just need to find one the right size for your shaft, and then find props with the right size hole to fit over the threads.

Brydon raised the point that you won't find collet adapters small enough. Really small drones usually just use press-fit props. You can use a small drop of superglue if necessary.

Comment: 4 collet-style adapters will likely weigh more than the current aircraft does. From the description, this is likely a small (6-8") foam body machine with 8mm brushless motors geared way down